# Sql change Data Type

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys

There is one column named Line_no (`smallint`) now. I want to change this column data type is `bigint`  ,but this column is primary key, and have so many tables has foreign key reference on it, so how to change it?, i need to change both `Sql server` and `oracle` database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all there's no easy way to do that currently. especially in Oracle, in order to change the data type, all the values of the field should be null. anyway the following process works for both Oracle and SQL Server:

1. make your database off line so that no operation can disturb our
   process.
2. Add a new field, say line_num having your new data type.
3. update the the new field with the line_no values for all records.
4. write a Stored Procedure to drop all the FKs referencing current
   PK, using meta data and **this SP should write the add FK command to
   dbms output, while it is looping, so that later you can execute them
   to add these FKs again in step 9**.
5. drop the primary key off the line_no field.
6. drop the field line_no.
7. rename the field
   line_num to line_no.
8. add the primary key on the new field.
9. run the commands generated in step 4 to add all the FKs again.
10. make your db online :)

Comment: I should mention, in step 4 you don't have to drop FKs, you can just disable them as well. and in step 9 you can just enable them back and there's no need to write add FK commands to dbms output anymore. of course I tested this on Oracle and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your DBMS. You may have to drop the foreign key constraints, alter the columns and re-create the constraints.

Comment: I need to change both sql and oracle.but there are so many tables .if i drop the foreign key one by one,maybe it take me more than one day.

Comment: @jack.li Update your question tags to include `oracle`.